# EF Pre-generated views and multiple Contexts

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In our environment we have more 200 tables and we are using EF 5.0 Code First to manage the database. Our software allows the users to modify the Entities and add Custom Fields to them.

Out of 200 more than 100 of them are system entities that are fixed and not customizable.

The initial load time of the application is more 2 minutes !!!!

We feel if we can somehow use EF pre-generated views for the fixed entities we can boost up the initial warm up time.

The question is, **under what condition(s) EF allows us to have pre-generated views for a number of entities within our project?**

Answer (score 0):

If your refer to Context menu option [image: Entity FrameWork - Generate views]

### Yes, the view is per Context

Then the resulting file is the Context in question.
Check the source of the generated view. Your will see the constructor refers to a context by name.
It also checks the view and Context still match using a context hash.

```
/// </Summary>
    public ViewsForBaseEntitySetsCC0A5F35D57704F5E501B804CB5CFFC8DCAD8C8E1AFC199B8C68FCD54D47FF7A()
    {
        this.EdmEntityContainerName = "THE DB CONTEXT NAME";
        this.StoreEntityContainerName = "CodeFirstDatabase";
        this.HashOverMappingClosure = "c7c56b72d1e7053b77daa9e4fb813dbb5ad00ae0a084f07f58399324dd70e906";
        this.HashOverAllExtentViews = "5fae06be83f62e86b71260bebb0e53a51d8b533588febbefbdcbaf628e514062";
        this.ViewCount = 62;
    }
```

### EDIT: Why an best practice info

See [Julie Lerman article on MSDN on bounded contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=JulieLerman)

Comment: Thanks for your response, so if put some of the entities on a separate Context. We should be able to generate views for those Models. What if this models have foreign keys between Context A and Context B? Also can the two contexts be in the same DLL?

Comment: then you cant model that constraint in the smaller context. But the DB will still enforce it.  I use ONE large context to create DB and several small to access.   Clearly the smaller contexts need logical groups if you want Context checks before you hit DB.

Comment: another question is it possible to add the same entity to both Context classes? There are scenarios that for eager-loading and joins where we need this.

Comment: absolutely, Indeed this is the whole idea. See Edit